# A given value must be the value that appears by default in a dynamic dropdown - JAVA

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I recovered a list of establishment through a servlet, with this list I travel the dropdown for that element are displayed dynamically.

So I recovered an value X of a field with the same servlet. This value is one of the elements of the list.

I want the value that appears by default in the dropdown will be the value X recovered.
here's the code:

```
<td>
    <select id="liste_Etab" name="liste_deroulante_etablissement" >

        <c:forEach var="e" items="${requestScope['listeEtablissement']}">                                   
            <option value="${e.id}">${e.libelle_etab}</option>
        </c:forEach>           
    </select>
</td> 

<!--  value recovered is:  ${requestScope['ChampPasse']} -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make option default in a select in `HTML`, you need to add a attribute `selected` to that option. So I would rewrite the code as

```
    <c:forEach var="e" items="${requestScope['listeEtablissement']}">  
        <c:if test="${e.id == X}">             
            <option value="${e.id}" selected>${e.libelle_etab}</option>
        </c:if>   
         <c:if test="${eid != X}">             
            <option value="${e.id}">${e.libelle_etab}</option>
        </c:if>    
    </c:forEach>           
</select>
```

Comment: yes, but it filled all the dropdown with the same test value

Comment: Thanks #Pradeep Patil your solution works well, I just changed a little trick in the 2nd if, I modified the operator of différence